# Searching an object array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a search function that will take an array of objects as the first argument and returns an array of all objects that have matching property/value pairs from the second argument. Here is what I have so far:

```
function where(collection, source) {

    var arr = [];
    var propName = Object.keys(source);     

    //console.log((collection[2][propName] == source[propName])? "true" : "false");

    var i = 0;
    var z = 0;
    var cl = collection.length;
    var pl = propName.length;

    for(z = 0; z < 1; z++){
        for(i= 0; i < cl; i++){             

            if(collection[i][propName[z]] == source[propName[z]]){

                //console.log(collection[i]);

                arr.push(collection[i]);

            }       

        }
    }

    console.log(arr);

}

where([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
       { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet", first: "Mercutio" });
```

It works when I have only one key/value pair as the search parameter like so:

```
where([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
       { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

but with two key/value pairs it only returns item that match to the first pair. Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW I'm looking to do this with vanilla JS.  Thanks Very Much!!!

Answer (score 3):

In `for(z = 0; z < 1; z++){` change *1*→*pl*, like so `for(z = 0; z < pl; z++){`, else you're just looping *z* through the value `0`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch that typo.